# Which Give fast performance between Core PHP or any other php framework

Tags: php, cakephp, performance

I want to develop ad posting website in which everything is customize and i also want that it give a very  fast response to user.
So what should i used to develop this application is Core php give a fast response than a framework like Cake,Yii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a framework [Phalcon](http://phalconphp.com/) specially created for the best response time and minimum overhead. It's written on C and compiled into php-extension (.dll/.so), so provide performance near to pure php. But you must be able to install extensions in you server/hosting.

Any framework written on php will give less or more overhead, because frameworks are made to be flexible and customizable, so in dedicated cases they do more operations you needed.

Frameworks overhead isn't so big to force you spending time with writing your own one. Network ping takes a lot more time to send a page than a server do to generate it. So in real life difference could be undistinguished, unless you want to keep thousands of users online and take care of every CPU microsecond.

From my experience, Symfony and Kohana are quite fast ones. If your site isn't a "very high loaded" one your visitors will not feel difference between a good framework and "handmade-core-php-code".